# How to gracefully import CSV files into Numbers.app v3?

Tags: numbers, import, csv

I have a process, which has worked faithfully for years in Numbers '09, whereby I download my Bank account data in CSV format, then drag that data directly into my Numbers sheet (after creating an appropriate number of blank rows).

This no longer works, and I can't find an option to import csv! A help search within numbers for 'csv' returns a [single result which describes exporting](http://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/3.0.1/#/tan886afc61b).

I've tried the old method, no dice.  Also, the menu option: Insert > Choose… doesn't permit .csv to be selected.

At the moment, my workaround is:

- drag the CSV onto the Numbers dock or task-switcher icon to create a temp sheet
- select and copy the content
- paste-and-match-format into my desired location
- close don't save the temp file

Doe anyone know a better way? A hack or hidden flag I can toggle to get the old functionality back?

Comment: Sounds like a case for http://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html I do not know of a better way than to notify Apple that the functionality is missing and should be patched with an update. Fingers crossed for soon

Comment: Tx! yeah, I submitted feedback, also started a thread here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/24438241#24438241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dragging and dropping a CSV onto a table works again since v3.2!

Currently in v6, I find that I can drag data onto an existing table, but it will overwrite the table's contents.

To preserve existing rows:

- select the file in Finder and `Copy`
- select the target cell in your target table (usually the last row in column A)
- `Paste`

When selecting the target cell, you may want to hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to ensure you're not in edit mode.

Comment: But what it does is create a new table within the spreadsheet. How do I add the data to an existing table without copying and pasting?

Comment: Not sure about 'without copying and pasting' @Calion - my objective is to avoid needing to create a temporary sheet... I've updated my instructions above - HTH! :)

Answer (score 8):

So the Apple thread recommended changing the txt to csv. This didn't work, my file was already csv, properly formated etc. No, changing ***to*** txt did the trick.
I'm finding it harder and harder to recommend switching from Microsoft to Apple. This sort thing just shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Would have been +1 for the method, but overwhelmed by the -1 for the gripe.

Comment: +1 for the method and because it seems a reasonable gripe for some very frustrating Mac behaviour

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a similar problem: after exporting a csv file from MySQL I tried to open directly into Numbers but it did not open correctly so I tried to drag the file onto an open sheet and it also and did not work.

Then I read lot of things on Internet about how Numbers deals with comma, so I exported the data once again switching comma (,) for semicolon (;) and voilà!

Comment: that did the trick for me too!

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution for getting a csv file to open correctly on a Mac. Change the csv file extension to txt. Then right click on it and open with Numbers.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the one provided by @mercergeoinfo

Answer (score 2):

Use 'tab' delimited fields - works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

if you've copied the CSV and know how to use the terminal:

```
pbpaste | tr , \\\t | pbcopy
```

will translate your comma delimited selection to tab-delimited right on the clipboard.

Comment: Who knew about `pbpaste`/`pbcopy` ?!!

Answer (score 1):

In Verson 6 of Numbers I was able to just highlight the data in the column of the CSV I needed and dragged the data to the excel template I had been given.

The company would no longer except the milage report from the app on my phone. The app would export a CSV file of the data.

The report from the app had a lot more columns and headers than the company supplied excel template.

I was able to just highlight the dates in the dates column of the report and drag it to the dates column of the template. The same with other necessary columns. Description, beginning and ending miles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so none of that worked for me.
here's how I did it. It required InDesign though.
So I converted the .vcf file online to .csv.
I then opened the .csv in Text Edit.
Then I copied the text and pasted it into an InDesign doc (A4 blank)
Highlight all of the text in the text box
In the top menu go to Tables > Convert Text To Table
Then simply copy the entire table (not the text box it's in, with the type tool you have to select the table cells).
Then open a Numbers blank doc.
Delete any table that is there.
go to File > Paste
Hey presto, you have an editable table with all of your contacts.

I know it's a bummer you need InDesign, but it's my go-to for solving issues like this.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Have both Numbers and excel on my mac and BOTH open a CSV file without any issue at all. Can right-click and also select which program I want to open the file with, works like a charm.

Comment: Trying to see what the relevance of your reference to .vcf (V-card file) is to the original question?

Answer (score -1):

Import the csv file into Excel.  Then "copy"  the entries and "paste" into Numbers.

But it is shocking that Numbers cannot import an industry-standard csv file.  Even more shocking when one remembers that we used to be able to.

Comment: If someone already has Excel installed then there doesn't appear to be a need to use Numbers.  Also, I don't see in the question where the OP states they have Excel installed.  Please see [answer] for tips on answering questions here.